# Python Scraping - My codes don't continue to find other elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37" 
url = "https://www.brookings.edu/events/" 
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent}) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml") 
 
document = Document() 
 
events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "module-content post-wrap post-count-even") 
for event in events: 
    event_name = event.find("h4", class_ = "title") 
    link = event.find("a") 
    try: 
        print(event_name.text) 
        document.add_paragraph(event_name, style='List Bullet') 
        print(link['href']) 
        document.add_paragraph(link['href']) 
    except: 
        continue
```

It stops after finding the first elements.

If you could show it in codes, I would be really appreciated because I'm having hardships to understand some points since I'm a total beginner. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 upcoming events, and with `soup.find_all("div", class_ = "module-content post-wrap post-count-even")` you get a list of all the events that also have the `post-count-even` class, the other event however has a different class called `post-count-odd` and therefor wasn't selected by `soup.find_all`.